# Not able to write image in desired folder in android

Tags: android

```
String fileName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+".jpg";
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/puzzlemaker/";
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
try{
    File file = new File(path);
file.mkdirs();
outStream = new FileOutputStream(path + fileName);
outStream.write(data);
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}catch(IOException e1){
e1.printStackTrace();
}finally{
try{
    outStream.close();
}catch(Exception e2){
    e2.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

The above code I have written to write an image in my described directory inside the sdcard. But everytime the image is stored inside the sdcard itself but not inside my described directory.

NOTE: I have already searched a lot of answers in the stackoverflow, but every answer is similar to this code. So I am unable to find the problem.

I have already uses the permission for writting in the external storage device in the manifest file.

Please help me, where I have the problem.

Comment: Where exactly is it stored then? Try to look at what is in path and fileName, that might give you a hint what is wrong

Comment: It is storing in the sdcard directory of the Gallery application.

Comment: is the directory created on the sd card?  `file.mkdirs()` returns true if successful and false otherwise.  Is it returning true?

Comment: I've just run his code and it works since we have file.mkdirs() before saving it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to create that directory before writing to it
`file.mkdirs();`